# How to detect if an object has moved out of the visible window in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my Android application I am using GLSurfaceView to draw 3d object like a box object. I animate this object by translating it using OpenGL ES apis. At some point during animation, the object would have gone out of the visible viewport window. At this point I must remove this object from the collection of other objects that are being drawn. How can I detect that the object has gone out of the view? Short code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a frustum class for android](http://code.google.com/p/rugl/source/browse/trunk/droid/DroidRUGL/src/com/ryanm/droid/rugl/util/geom/Frustum.java), a port of the code from [here](http://www.racer.nl/reference/vfc_markmorley.htm). It allows you to extract the frustum parameters from OpenGL, and then test various geometric primitives (points, spheres, axis-aligned cuboids) for inclusion in the view volume.

Two things to look out for:

1. The should-be-redundant error handling code in the update() method. See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/72cf40ad9615835c#) for the story on this. Looks like it's a heisenbug.
2. extractFromOGL() uses glGetFloat - this method is not implemented in the PixelFlinger software renderer. If you are targeting really low-end devices or using the emulator, you'll have to compute your projection and modelview matrices yourself and call update() manually.

Comment: thanks. Finally solved the problem after getting good understanding of modelview matrix.

Answer (score 1):

What you you're looking from is called [viewing frustum culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum_culling#Viewing_frustum_culling).

> The viewing frustum is a geometric
>   representation of the volume visible
>   to the virtual camera. Naturally,
>   objects outside this volume will not
>   be visible in the final image, so they
>   are discarded. Often, objects lie on
>   the boundary of the viewing frustum.
>   These objects are cut into pieces
>   along this boundary in a process
>   called clipping, and the pieces that
>   lie outside the frustum are discarded
>   as there is no place to draw them.

Several tutorials on the topic:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/viewfrustum/

http://www.crownandcutlass.com/features/technicaldetails/frustum.html

Comment: I am looking for OpenGL ES Api that is something like given an object geometry, it would test if the object is outside of viewport window or not and return the test result.

Comment: There is no API for that in OpenGL ES. You need to implement frustum culling yourself as I pointed out above.